# wpf vb.net Datagrid image in row depending on value in cell

Tags: wpf, vb.net

This is the code i use but it is notworking

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PinkRow" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Rank}" Value="Master">
                 <Setter Property="Source" Value="A_Cancel.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RANK}" Value="Bosun">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RANK}" Value="">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="yellow" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

If field rank has the value "Master" i want the image A_cancel.png

Answer (score 0):

The C# is case sensitive, so the `Rank` and `RANK` are different properties. Use proper property name in your bindings. Also you must mention in your Setter the `TargetName` for `Image` element.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Rank}" Value="Master">
     <Setter TargetName="ImageElementName" Property="Source" Value="A_Cancel.png"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But i get a error, The member "Source" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Comment: Which control must show the image A_Cancel.png? `ImageElementName` is just placeholder. You must pass the concrete element name in `TargetName`.